# Fatal access conflict detected when swapping array values in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swap

I am trying to use the direct swap method available in Swift 4.2 to swap values of an array storing modal data, but it crashed. Can someone please suggest me why this is not working.?

```
   if modalArray.count >= 2{
            swap(&modalArray[0], &modalArray[1])
        }
```

The Error I got is:

> Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x600001c4cb08, but modification
>   requires exclusive access

When I jumped to swap I got the definition that says it should work. Refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Actually the definition says it **won't** work and it also provides you with an alternative - see Joshua's answer.

Comment: To explain further because the terminology used by Apple might not be completely clear, the phrase "... must not alias each other" means they must not refer to the same underlying thing. That includes not being elements in the same collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `swapAt(_:_:)` method

```
if modalArray.count >= 2{
   modalArray.swapAt(0, 1)
}
```

On why yours does not work, `swap` should not be used on Mutable Collections.

Apple Doc for `swap`

> The two arguments must not alias each other. To swap two elements of a mutable collection, use the swapAt(*:*:) method of that collection instead of this function.

Comment: This seems to work too `(array[0], array[1]) = (array[1], array[0])` although it won't take advantage of any internal optimisations that might be available to `swapAt`